# "input to your method" or "input for your method"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the two is correct:

- *"Is this a valid **input to** your method?"*
- *"Is this a valid **input for** your method?"*

In this context, a method is a *function* with a set of *parameters* that may or may not *return* a *value*. I use the words *input* and *parameter* (or a *set of parameters*) here interchangeably.

The general Wikipedia page for [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function) lists several sub-pages. In the context of this question, consider this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(computer_science)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137003/discussion-on-question-by-janez-kuhar-input-to-your-method-or-input-for-your).